# R Shinydashboard submenuitems using same UI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a basic app with a `MenuItem` that when clicked displays a plot of a specific variable. The variable can be chosen from a `SelectInput` in the UI for this `MenuItem`.

However, what I'd really like to do is to have the possible variables be displayed as `subMenuItems` of the original `MenuItem`, so that when one is clicked it grabs the currently selected variable and renders the plot. This looks visually neater to me than using a `SelectInput` dropdown.

I was trying to get this working by having each `tabItem` link to the same `uiOutput` that displays the appropriate content, but Shiny doesn't seem to like having multiple tabs with the same output. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Code example that doesn't work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(), 
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
        textOutput("res")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem("dashboard", "Dashboard tab content"),
            tabItem("widgets", "Widgets tab content"),
            tabItem("chartsHome", "Main charts content"),
            tabItem("subitem1", uiOutput("chart")),
            tabItem("subitem2", uiOutput("chart")) 
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$res <- renderText({
        paste("You've selected:", input$tabs)
    })
    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
            id = "tabs",

            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
            menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets"),
            menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), tabName="chartsHome",
                     menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
                     menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
            )
        )
    })

    output$chart <- renderUI({
        if (input$tabs == "subitem1") {
            HTML("Chart with first variable as output")
        } else if (input$tabs == "subitem2") {
            HTML("Chart with second variable as output")
        }
    })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have duplicate IDs, they have to be unique. You can investigate these yourself by right clicking on the page and then `inspect`, click on `console` and you will see the errors. For you its `Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID chart`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
    textOutput("res")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard", "Dashboard tab content"),
      tabItem("widgets", "Widgets tab content"),
      tabItem("chartsHome", "Main charts content"),
      tabItem("subitem1", uiOutput("chart")),
      tabItem("subitem2", uiOutput("chart2")) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderText({
    paste("You've selected:", input$tabs)
  })
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
      id = "tabs",

      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets"),
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), tabName="chartsHome",
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
      )
    )
  })

  toRender <- reactive({
    if (input$tabs == "subitem1") {
      HTML("Chart with first variable as output")
    } 
    else if (input$tabs == "subitem2") {
      HTML("Chart with second variable as output")
    }
    else{
      return()
    }
  })

  output$chart <- renderUI({
    toRender()
  })

  output$chart2 <- renderUI({
    toRender()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Specifying the renderUI for each `output$chart` is a lot of duplicated code. I imagine I could programmatically generate these as the server will know how many variables can be chosen. Will this amount of duplicate code and IDs make the page load slowly?

Comment: Yes it will be slower, however the page must have unique ids, you might want to think how to refactor some of the code, so theres very little to add. See the edit with the `toRender` added

Comment: This works, but I can't find how to dynamically generate the `tabItems` for the `subitems` (but it's trivial to get `menuSubItems` generated with `renderMenu` and `menuItemOutput`). This is because if I replace a `tabItem` with a `uiOutput` that returns a list of `tabItems`, it gets wrapped in a `div` and so the tab items aren't recognised.